# SpringBoot - MySQL

Tags: mysql, spring-boot

I have created a Spring Boot REST API with inbuilt Apache Derby database. It worked fine. Now I have to integrate it with MySQL. I have updated POM.XML and configured the driver.

Expense.java

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "vendor")
public class Expense {

    @Id
    @Column
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private String vendorId;
    @Column
    private String vendorName;
    @Column
    private int vendorPhone;
    @Column
    private int vendorBalance;
    @Column
    private int vendorChequeAmount;

    public String getVendorId() {
        return vendorId;
    }

    public void setVendorId(String vendorId) {
        this.vendorId = vendorId;
    }


    public String getVendorName() {
        return vendorName;
    }


    public void setVendorName(String vendorName) {
        this.vendorName = vendorName;
    }


    public int getVendorPhone() {
        return vendorPhone;
    }


    public void setVendorPhone(int vendorPhone) {
        this.vendorPhone = vendorPhone;
    }


    public int getVendorBalance() {
        return vendorBalance;
    }


    public void setVendorBalance(int vendorBalance) {
        this.vendorBalance = vendorBalance;
    }


    public int getVendorChequeAmount() {
        return vendorChequeAmount;
    }


    public void setVendorChequeAmount(int vendorChequeAmount) {
        this.vendorChequeAmount = vendorChequeAmount;
    }    

    public Expense(String vendorId, String vendorName, int vendorPhone, int vendorBalance, int vendorChequeAmount) {
        super();
        this.vendorId = vendorId;
        this.vendorName = vendorName;
        this.vendorPhone = vendorPhone;
        this.vendorBalance = vendorBalance;
        this.vendorChequeAmount = vendorChequeAmount;
    }
```

application.properties

```
server.port = 8087
server.contextPath=/expense-tracker
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/web_customer_tracker
spring.datasource.username=springstudent
spring.datasource.password=springstudent
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyHbmImpl
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy
```

[Please click for the MySQL details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVs2M.jpg)

When I run using Postman, I am getting 404 error. Something is wrong with MySQL configuration. Please help to identify it. Thanks
[EDIT]

ExpenseController.Java

```
package com.shef.expensetracker.expense;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200", maxAge = 3600)
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/vendors")
public class ExpenseController {

    @Autowired
    private ExpenseService expenseService;

    @GetMapping
    public List<Expense> getAllExpenses(){
        return expenseService.findAll();
    }

    @GetMapping(path = {"/{vendorId}"})
    public Expense getExpense(@PathVariable String vendorId){
        return expenseService.getExpenseById(vendorId);
    }

    @PostMapping
    public void addExpense(@RequestBody Expense expense){
        expenseService.addExpense(expense);
    }

    @PutMapping(path = {"/{vendorId}"})
    public void updateExpense(@RequestBody Expense expense, @PathVariable String vendorId){
        expenseService.updateExpense(expense,vendorId );
    }

    @DeleteMapping(path = {"/{vendorId}"})
    public void deleteExpense( @PathVariable String vendorId){
        expenseService.deleteExpense(vendorId );
    }


}
```

ExpenseService.Java

```
package com.shef.expensetracker.expense;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class ExpenseService {


    @Autowired
    private ExpenseRepository expenseRepository;
    /*private List<Expense> expenses = new ArrayList<>(
            Arrays.asList(new Expense("1","Chicken", 1234, 500, 100),
                    new Expense("2","Mutton", 1234, 600, 100),
                    new Expense("3","Beef", 1234, 700, 100)
                    ));*/

    public List<Expense> findAll(){
        List<Expense> expenses = new ArrayList<>();
        expenseRepository.findAll().forEach(expenses::add);
        return expenses;
    }



    public void addExpense(Expense expense) {

        //expenses.add(expense);
        expenseRepository.save(expense);
    }

    public Expense getExpenseById(String vendorId){
        return expenseRepository.findOne(vendorId);
    }

    public void updateExpense(Expense expense, String vendorId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        expenseRepository.save(expense);
    }

    public void deleteExpense(String vendorId) {
        expenseRepository.delete(vendorId);

    }

}
```

ExpenseTrackerApplication.Java

```
package com.shef.expensetracker;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ExpenseTrackerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ExpenseTrackerApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Http code `404` means that the resource you asked for could not be found so the error should be in your `Controller` class. Could you please provide the source code of this class and your main application class (the one with the `main` method) as well?

Comment: Hello Florian .. I have added the codes above. Thank you for checking it. I am really new to Springboot

Comment: what does the error say? what request are you making?

Comment: 404 error, I am making a GET request. Does the code looks fine to you?

Comment: Please specify the exact URL you are sending the request to. Code looks fine but we cannot tell very much from this without knowing the exact path you are requesting.